# human viewport parameters

Tags: modeling

I am a newbie playing with the new Landscape mesh tool. My problem is, say, I generate 3000x3000 m(eters)^2 mesh of terrain. The human viewport would be expressed in cms at most, while blender's is arbitrary. Can I somehow view the terrain while modelling, at the height of a human, using human viewport parameters, not that of a god?

EDIT:
Both the answer(s) and the comments were very helpful, but also take a look at this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0mcAL3sWRM

Comment: I think i may have an answer for you, but i don't understand "The human viewport would be expressed in cms at most, while blender's is arbitrary." If you explain i might be able to help.

Comment: @ARadish I was talking in terms of the viewing frustum. This can be calculated from the FOV. If the FOV is reasonable, which it seems not to be. That is, the frustum is characterized by 6 parameters (left, right, bottom, top, near, far). The first 4 define the viewport, which seems too large to me. Or perhaps the near (projection) plane is too close, or the FOV is wrong.

Comment: I think I'm more confused than before. You must be smarter than me cause I don't even know what the heck a funstrum is besides when your having fun playing guitar. fun-strum. Sorry I can't help.... ,:*(

Comment: @ARadish That's a frustum. It's a pyramid, whose top has been [cut off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum). But don't dispair, please write an answer, because I still don't know how to position the viewing camera just above the terrain, also is there a way to disable orbiting around a point (simulate rotating the head)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the view with this in the <kbd>N</kbd> panel:
[image]

Lens controls the field of view, start and end Clip control near and far.
For more control on left, right, bottom and top, you'll need to use a camera and change resolution. In viewport, it's display size.

for walk/fly mode, use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. for parameters, in user prefs, input tab, view navigation : walk and gravity for a FPS like (<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> jump, <kbd>space</kbd> teleport) movement.
[image]

with gravity, you need a ground (plane or any object).

Comment: There a way to disable orbiting around a point, when pressing the middle mouse button?

Comment: in user preferences, input tab, you change the orbit style to trackball.